# Deleting up to a certain line in Vim

Tags: linux, vim, text-editor

I know that to delete n lines, the command is [n]dd, where n is the number of lines to delete.

But what if I want to delete up to a certain line number? Say, if I'm on line 65 and I want to delete up to line 126 without having to do the math, how could I do that?

Comment: The "delete", "yank", etc., commands are very generic in vim: they can take any "movement operator".  `d/hello` will delete from the cursor to the next `hello` for example.  `d''` will delete from the current position to the line of the last position, etc.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

d126G

Delete, line number, go.

A lot of commands in Vim can be followed by a move command to specify the scope.

Comment: +1'ing this as it requires fewer characters (and at least to me, fits far more into the "language of vim") than the other options.

Comment: I like this because you don't have to use the : command, which seems relatively clumsier.

Comment: Exvept that you can log your ':' commands to some file (viminfo), and it can be later reused. I do love 'q:' then '/searchforsomething' then hit enter...

Comment: is it possibe to delete a current line as in the editing mode

Comment: @Erogol `dd` deletes the current line.

Comment: Is G necessary? I've just tried this with d123 and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 43):

Use this command:
`65,126d`

Answer (score 25):

```
:.,126d
```

`.` is the actual line. If you want delete from the next line, you can use `.+1` instead.

Comment: This is safer for me, because I can't always look at the keyboard and verify the number.

Answer (score 18):

```
:,126d
```

all done.

Comment: I don't think there is a shorter syntax than this! (But I'll be very glad if I'm wrong)